# JTextArea not appearing in JFrame - Java

Tags: java, jframe, jtextarea

I'm creating a simple GUI consisting of a full-window (J)TextArea. I've created a JFrame window and a JTextArea text area and set up both. Additionally I created some colors and the font I want to use with the text area.

Upon running the class, the window pops up as expected, however the text area is not there.

I have set the text area to visible, so that can't be a problem.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create and set up window
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Console");

        window.setSize(800, 500);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //create fonts and colors
        Color gray = new Color(34, 34, 34);
        Color lightGray = new Color(207, 191, 173);
        Font consolas = new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 15);

        //create and set up text area
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

        text.setSize(800, 500);
        text.setVisible(true);

        //text area font and colors
        text.setBackground(gray);
        text.setForeground(lightGray);
        text.setFont(consolas);

        text.append("Text");

    }   
}
```

And what results is a blank window named 'Console'.

How do I fix the JTextArea so that it shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your JTextArea to the JFrame with the add- Method 
`window.add(text);`

Another point make the frame visible after adding. `window.setVisible(true);` in the last line. Because sometimes there are strange layouterrors.

Comment: Should I add the text area to the window before or after 'setting it up', ie. setting the font, the foreground and background colors, etc. or does it not matter?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 what about `window.getContentPane().add(text);` instead of `window.add(text)`?

Comment: Also, could you rephrase the second part of your answer? I can't understand what you are trying to say. Thanks

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam ... afaik the add method is overriden and forward to the contentPane http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html (first part) but you are right its the better solution

Comment: @Jacob i mean when you make the frame visible before adding the Textarea, it can be, that the area is not visible sometimes.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Okay, so you mean I should put window.setVisible after I have added every component